# Tengo un problema para ordenar el diccionario por valor de forma descendente

Tags: python, diccionarios, ordenamiento

```
campeonato = [["Boca", 19, 0, 0], ["River", 0, 1, 18], ["San Lorenzo", 8, 5, 2]]

equipos = {}

def puntaje(campeonato):

    for i in campeonato:

        puntaje = 3 * i[1] + 1 * i[2] + 0 * i[3]
        equipos[i[0]] = puntaje

    return equipos

def ordenar(equipos):

    equipos_ordenados = sorted(equipos.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)

    return equipos_ordenados

puntaje(campeonato)

print(equipos)

ordenar(equipos)

print(equipos)
```

El problema es que me devuelve el mismo diccionario que el generado en la función puntaje y no está ordenado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasas es que llamas a ordenar, pero no guardas el resultado de la función.

Solución:

```
equipos = ordenar(equipos)
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió y logré solucionarlo.